# Why OpenCV project's multi thread are slower than single one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, pthreads, loadimage

I have written some codes to load 1025 images with OpenCV to process them;these codes are in two versions :
 single thread and multi threads; problem is that the results of codes have confused me; because single thread version is faster than multi threads.

What do you think about it?? what's wrong ?

my codes are below.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "ctpl.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define threaded

void loadImage(int id, int param0) {
    stringstream stream;
    stream << "/home/me/Desktop/Pics/pic (" << param0 << ").jpg";
    Mat x = imread(stream.str(), IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_8);
}

int main() {
#ifdef threaded
    ctpl::thread_pool p(8);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1025; i++) {
        p.push(loadImage,i);
    }
//    for (int i = 0; i < 1025; ++i) {
//        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
//    }
#else
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1025; i++) {
        stringstream stream;
        stream << "/home/me/Desktop/Pics/pic (" << i << ").jpg";
        Mat x = imread(stream.str(), IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_8);
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with less threads perhaps the # of cores you have? I assume you don't have 1025 cores even if you have a fast SSD that will allow you to load 1025 files at the same time efficiently. I also assume your memory bandwith is not able to handle processing 1025 images at the same time.

Comment: Why would you expect loading images to benefit from multiple threads? You have increased cost due to thread creation, destruction, and synchronization, and reading from storage doesn't parallelize well anyway. Also, your multithreaded version requires *much* more memory, which reduces caching efficiency drastically.

Comment: 1025 threads. That's insane.

Comment: no; I expected OS to control threads.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, you can't measure threading performance reliably with "toy" code. This code reads images and then throws them away, not doing any actual work. This leaves no real work whose performance you can actually benchmark, so you wind up measuring things like thread creation, synchronization, scheduling latency -- everything except the time it takes to do the work you were trying to do efficiently!

Comment: @MohsenTi The API you are using is too low-level for that. There are thread pool APIs that allow you to schedule large numbers of tasks at once, but you are actually creating 1,025 threads because you are using the platform's threading API directly rather than any code that will intelligently manage concurrency.

Comment: Agreed, A thread pool would be a much better solution.

Comment: I add thread pool to my code but result is same. this is the thread pool https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl

Comment: I am not familiar with that code does it set the number of threads to 4 or 8 or something sane?

Comment: Also are you loading from a SSD or ramdisk? I mean having more than 1 thread for loading with a hard drive will likely be counter productive unless the loading part is CPU intensive. If the loading is CPU intensive a sane first guess on the maximum # of threads is the number of cores you have.

Comment: Yes, this library run task with 8 worker and each worker is a thread.

Comment: This code load images from a hdd but reading a file is to faster than decoding image; I think disk speed is not limit of code.